# how to derive this elliptic integral?

Tags: cv.complex-variables, mp.mathematical-physics, hypergeometric-functions, string-theory, hyperelliptic-curves

I am reading the article arXiv: 2207.09961, there are some interesting elliptic integrals, i.e. the formula (3.7) and (3.8). You can also see this image

[image]

where $p_0(z)=\sqrt{-Q_0(z)}$ and $Q_0(z)=-\frac{\omega^2\ L^2(z^4+1)-z^2(l+2)^2}{z^4}$. It is a period integral as the author said.
However I have no good idea to derive it. Could you tell me some hints? Thank you very much!

Comment: Better to type out the equation in full, than have an image like this

Comment: Check [DLMF Ch.19](https://dlmf.nist.gov/19) a handbook reference on Elliptic Integrals.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. @David Roberts